# How do I lock out writes to a specific table while several queries execute?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table set up in my sql server that keeps track of inventory items (in another database) that have changed. This table is fed by several different triggers. Every 15 minutes a scheduled task runs a batch file that executes a number of different queries that send updates on the items flagged in this table to update several ecommerce websites. The last query in the batch file resets the flags.

As you can imagine there is potential to lose changes if an item is flagged while this batch file is running. I have worked around this by replaying the last 25 hours of updates every 24 hours, just in case this scenario happened. It works, but IMO is kind of clumsy.

What I would like to do is delay any writes to this table until my script finishes, and resets the flags on all the rows that were flagged when the script started. Then allow all of these delayed writes to happen.

I've looked into doing this with table hints (TABLOCK) but this seems to be limited to one query--unless I'm misunderstanding what I have read, which is certainly possible. I have several that run in succession. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Alex
Could you modify your script into a stored procedure that extracts all the data into a temporary table using a select statement that applies a lock to the production table. You could then drop your lock on the main table and do all your processing in the temporary table (or permanent table built for the purpose) away from the live system. It will be a lot slower and put more load on your SQL box but speed shouldn't be an issue if you have a point in time snapshot of it.

If that option is not applicable then maybe you could play with wrapping the whole thing in a transaction and putting a table lock on your production table with the first select statement.

Good luck mate

Comment: Thanks Gerald, that sounds like a workable plan. i can select into a temp table all the flagged records and reset the flags in the next step. Doing that would be instantaneous, with very little chance of a rouge write getting in.